# PDO Create table not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Just having trouble inserting a new table using PDO. The error I am getting is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''25500' ( `id`
>   INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAUL' at
>   line 149440 does not exist!

Please note that $id is the table name.

```
function createTable($dbh, $id, $description)
{
try {
$stmt = "CREATE TABLE '$id' (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`prodtitle` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`unitsize` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`price` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`wasprice` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`specprice` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) COMMENT = '$description'";

if($dbh->exec($stmt) !== false) echo 'The sites table is created';
} 
catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

It must be something simple but I just cant pick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TableName should not be wrap with single quote as it is not an string literal. Try to change single quote with backtick,

```
$stmt = "CREATE TABLE `$id` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`prodtitle` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`unitsize` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`price` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`wasprice` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`specprice` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) COMMENT = '$description'"
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved me alot of pain!